# Why my wall sockets are buzzing when I plug something in?

Tags: electrical, socket, cord-and-plug

Problem: So whenever I plug something into the wall socket, it gives a little electrical buzzing noise, a bit faint but i can hear it. It stops when its pluged all the way in.

The plug is loose in the socket, so should I replace the sockets? I'm a bit new to this, what should I do?

I have tried to ignore it and just plug stuff in, but I worry it may create a huge problem either in the devices I plug in or possibly damage to the home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The socket spring is sprung.  The buzzing says you have arcing in there.  Very bad news.  I suspect the wire is getting loose because it's a type of connection we call a "back stab" where you jab the wire in a hole and a barbed spring grabs it, I bet that has also sprung. I would shut off the breaker and swap the outlets for quality grades.

How do you learn how to do that?  Libraries and big-box home improvement shops have a collection of books that teach home electical repairs.   Look through all of them and find one that "speaks to you".

When you shop for outlets, you'll find there's a 75 cent tier, a $3-4 tier and a $10-12 tier.  You want the $3-4 tier.

Never use the "back stabs" on the outlet where you jab the wire in, and it grabs it.  The springs are unreliable - this very thing happens.  It is OK to use "clamp-screw" types where you stick the wire into a slot and then screw down the screw to clamp it down.  Those are in the $3-4 tier.   Or use the screw terminals.

Also be on the lookout for "aluminum wire" - it is silver or gray instead of orangish copper.  Aluminum wire requires very special handling - check back here.

Comment: This is a very good answer+

Comment: I just dont know much about all this. Is arcing that bad? i put my device through the night in it, should i be concerned? any video i can follow? whats back stabs?

Comment: Arcing is cataclysmic.  It's one of the things that burns houses down.   I kill it on sight.  The arcing is actually corroding/consuming metal parts inside the outlet.   As the socket burns up, the gap gets wider, the arc gets hotter, and either a house fire starts, or so much metal is burned up that the gap is too wide to arc.  You are literally playing with fire.

Comment: This is what i have to replace it with  http://imgur.com/a/PA4Mi      i dont have a choice, it looks like a good product. I see the screws and holes for wires to go through. It has letter L and letter N, on each hole. Im guessing i should wrap wire around each.

Comment: Spring connectors are not bad by definition. You can get bad springs or cheap screws, which can't be tightened enough. I've seen German quality spring connecters as a test overloaded heavily, where the insulation of the cables melted long before the spring failed. A good quality spring never gets loose, as a screw can, because the copper will flow over years.

Comment: Not sure if i should start another question. I did it, but i think the insulation doesnt go inside the holes in the back recpetacle and i left a bit of bare copper wire sticking out as i stripped the insulation. I had to because the wire was damaged. am i paranoid for thinking thats dangerous and i should redo it?